# Inheritance VS composition in terms of flexibility

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

I am reading Head First design patterns and one point against inheritance is that it hard codes the behavior where as composition is more flexible. I haven't been able to completely understand it. Consider the following classes:

```
interface Flyable{
    void fly();
}
// Imagine this duck is exposed as a Spring bean named "mallardDuck" :
class MallardDuck implements Flyable {
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("Flying slowly");
    }
}
class IndianDuck {
    Flyable f;
    public void setF(Flyable f) {
        this.f = f;
    }
    public void fly() {
        f.fly();
    }       
}
// Imagine this duck is exposed as a Spring bean named "indianFlight" :
class FlyCautiously implements Flyable {
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("Flying cautiously");
    }
}
```

So Indian duck uses composition VS Mallard duck using inheritance. Consider the following client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Inheritance:
    Flyable f = (Flyable) context.getBean("mallardDuck"); // Use of Spring
    f.fly();

    // Composition
    IndianDuck d = new IndianDuck();
    Flyable f = (Flyable) context.getBean("indianFlight"); 
    d.setF(f);
    d.fly();
}
```

Now suppose I want both the ducks to be able to fly in a super fast mode, I need the following changes for inheritance:

1. Extend MallardDuck and create a MallardSuperFastDuck.
2. In the application context point mallardDuck to MallardSuperFastDuck instead of MallardDuck.

For composition I need almost the same steps:

1. Extend Flyable and create a new SuperFastFlyer (that implements Flyable)
2. Point indianFlight to the new object SuperFastFlyer

I cannot understand why inheritance is less flexible in above case. I am sure I am missing the point but I posted this after thinking too much.

Can someone please explain what I am missing here?

Also - it's said that with composition you tie the behavior at run time. Really? If i need new behavior altogether - I have to write a new class, compile the code again. So this is compile time too.

Please explain.

Thanks

Comment: The tradeoff here is not something that you can just read about and understand -- you need to get some experience and then it becomes fairly natural.  Artificially sticking to one scheme or another because it's the "right way" will often lead you to grief.

Comment: @nachokk does that mean the code above is all right using inheritance or composition? Also, Head First also has described side effects of using interfaces while inheriting and what it says is that a change in behavior requires you to change the sub class which I think is not always the case as depicted above.

Comment: Well i think you never should change your interface, is a contract.. you can always create a new interface and extends to the old one, then you don't have to change subclasses, `open closed principle` and perhaps `segregation interface principle`. Besides composition is more flexible cause you in runtime can change behaviour this is truth, see this in `Strategy Pattern` or `State pattern` that are quite simple.

Comment: Never change your interface???  You'd last about 15 minutes that way.

Comment: @HotLicks i mean never change in a production code, if i want to extend it i can always create `public interface newInterface extends OldInterface` that what i mean, to don't have to change subclasses if they should not change.. sorry if my english is not clear